# Using Angular Material Design Components that are imported/exported from their own module

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I've been working with Angular 6 for a while now, but the modules are very confusing to me for some reason. After developing my apps with mostly Bootstrap, I've decided to switch over to Angular Material Design for the project I am currently working on.

I read in the docs at [Material Design Docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-3-import-the-component-modules) and I can't figure the module part out. I get that I can just import the Material modules in my `app.module` file and use them, but I want to use a separate `module` file specifically for the Material components, to keep my `app.module` more organized (as the docs say is possible).

So I created my `material.module` file and put all the components I want to use in the import and export arrays in the file. I then imported the `material.module` in my `app.module`. I tried to use a component, i.e. the MatSnackBar, in a page's .ts file, but it cannot find the `MatSnackBar` without importing it from `@angular/material`.

I know there's something wrong with my setup and I've tried it multiple ways, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Can someone shed some light on this for me? Also if you know of any good courses on Pluralsight or good write-up tutorials on actually using Material Design, those resources would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to use a component, i.e. the MatSnackBar, in a page's .ts file, but it cannot find the MatSnackBar without importing it from @angular/material

And that's perfectly fine. You will have to import it also inside your component .ts file.

Your approach of creating separate module for material components is defeniteley a good idea I see very often.

Comment: So even though I included it in the module file, I still have to import it from @angular/material? Could you explain why? I'm just trying to wrap my head around the concept

Comment: You import in component .ts MatSnackBar as a class - and it is necessary. Assuming it were not mandatory - @angular/core and @angular/animations both have functions with same name: style, trigger, state etc. - it would couse some problems. Importing in module however lets you use tags of components.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was confused, but using your suggestion and playing around with it, it makes much more sense